# How can I lock in just one place

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two threads and a `Queue<string>`. The first thread doing some performance critical work in a loop and it checks the `Queue<string>` each iteration, grabbing the string if `Queue` is not empty.

Now I need the second thread to *safely* put strings in a `Queue`. Only the second thread should **wait** when the 1st thread isn't doing anything with the `Queue`. I don't want to use `lock` because it will be blocking the 1st thread eventually slowing it down.

How can I do that? I tried to surround only `Enqueue()` in my 2nd thread with the lock statement, but the ReSharper is warning me that:

> the field is sometimes used inside synchronized block and sometimes used without synchronization.

So I guess I'm not doing it right.

Comment: Throwing it out there in case this fits your need. Can't you use [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Sounds like ConcurrentQueue<T> can be useful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39602754/1771817) to a similar question I asked recently.  Entering the lock for every manipulation of the Queue is what guarantees thread safety/memory visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either don't use `Queue` or don't use `lock` (but a [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) for example). In this case I suggest [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx).